# How can I install emacs correctly on OS X?

Tags: macos, emacs

I tried doing:

```
brew install emacs --HEAD --use-git-head --with-cocoa --with-gnutls --with-rsvg --with-imagemagick
```

But when I do emacs --version

```
emacs --version
-bash: /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.5/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs: No such file or directory
```

When I do

```
brew info emacs

emacs: stable 25.2 (bottled), HEAD
```

I am an EMACS newbie. It's a bit difficult to understand. And I may have deleted the default Emacs

Comment: Maybe not what you're looking for, but try taking a look at AquaMacs. It's easy to run on osx

Comment: @Duxducis Thanks. I would prefer to run the GNU version...

Comment: Gotcha, well these are the precompiled binaries of the GNU version for OSX https://emacsformacosx.com/

Comment: That error from bash suggests that the `emacs` you are running is a wrapper script which explicitly wants to run `/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.5/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs`. Running `which emacs` ought to tell you where that wrapper script is.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You don't need some of those arguments your passing to brew to get the latest
emacs 26.1. Try the following

Remove emacs

```
brew uninstall emacs
```

Clean out any previously downloaded source files

```
brew cleanup
```

Check your brew installation is OK

```
brew doctor
```

The message you get when you run emacs --version indicates a partially installed version of emacs 24. Running brew doctor should help identify the problems.

Make sure your running the most recent brew

```
brew update
```

Upgrade any brew stuff you have in case any of them are pre-requisites

```
brew upgrade
```

then install emacs with

```
brew install emacs --with-cocoa --with-librsvg --with-imagemagick@6
```

Watch for messages from brew. During the install, brew use to advise running

```
brew linkapps emacs
```

afterwards to make sure the new version is linked to the /Applications folder
correctly. I suspect this may have been the missing step in your install. While the brew manual suggests this command is deprecated, it also says to use a cask version instead. I found some issues with the cask version, so prefer to use the locally built vers (cask version uses emacsforosx binaries). It isn't clear if you should still run linkapps when using the non cask version - however, the install should tell you, so make sure you look at all the output (the message is not at the end, but further up in the install process output).

The other arguments you had are only necessary if you want to install the latest
development version, which is not a good idea if your just starting out. all you
want is emacs 26.1

Make sure that /usr/local/bin is in your path before /usr/bin to avoid emacs
referencing the very old version of Emacs bundled with OSX.

Comment: Hasn't linkapps been deprecated?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake re: delete. Use uninstall or remove. WRT linkapps, wasn't aware it had been depricated. However, after you have uninstalled emacs, check that there isn't an old Emacs.app in either /Applicaitons or ~/Applicaitons - if there is, remove it before installing with homebrew. Note that there is also a brew cask emacs, which is 'recommended' by some (it uses the macforosx binaries). I tried it and found some issues, so reverted back to locally built version.

Comment: I get the warnings:
    Warning: emacs: this formula has no --with-imagemagick option so it will be ignored!
    Warning: emacs: this formula has no --with-rsvg option so it will be ignored!

Comment: Can you please comment on the `Warning: emacs: this formula has no --with-imagemagick option so it will be ignored!` issue. Cheers.

Comment: From time to time, brew will change what arguments are supported by a formula or the name/format of the argument. In this case, both the rsvg and imagemagick optons have change. Do a 'brew info emacs' to get a full list of the current command line arguments and select the ones you need.

Comment: @TimX - Edited your answer to add the updated arguments and add a new `brew info emacs` step but my edits were rejected by the reviewers. If you would update your answer to include these changes I'm certain other readers would appreciate it.

Comment: This is out of date. `brew cask install emacs` is the way to go. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47155790/79790

Comment: Actually, it isn't out of date. If you want to install emacs from sources, the above is still the correct way to do it via homebrew (though you don't need to do the linkapps step anymore). However, if you just want to install a binary and not build from source, the brew cask install emacs is the way to go

Comment: why do we need `--with-cocoa --with-librsvg --with-imagemagick@6` ?

Comment: @alper - For emacs 26.1, you needed those options because they were not enabled by default and they add useful functionality. The only one which is probably absolutely necessary is --with-cocoa as that ensure the macOS GUI libs are linked and you have a GUI version of Emacs. Note that installing from source is no longer the only option and you can now install from binary cask, so options won't be needed. Also note that options are different for later versions of Emacs, so should always check what they are

Answer (score 61):

This is an update for April 2019, Mac OSX mojave 10.14.4 [discussion on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/agvx2m/no_option_withcocoa_in_homebrew_formula_anymore/)

It seems that the cocoa option is not available on hombrew also the --head. So you can:

```
brew cask install emacs #is the preferred from emacs wiki
brew install --cask emacs #using new cask syntax
```

and if you want to do the equal setup from brew without using cask, you can use this:

[emacs-head](https://github.com/daviderestivo/homebrew-emacs-head)

```
brew tap daviderestivo/emacs-head
brew install emacs-head --HEAD --with-cocoa --with-librsvg --with-imagemagick@7 --with-json --with-multicolor-fonts --with-no-frame-refocus --with-mailutils --with-dbus --with-modules
```

getting this

```
ls -l $(which emacs)                                                                                                                                                                                               
lrwxr-xr-x  1 toni  admin  45 23 abr 19:26 /usr/local/bin/emacs -> ../Cellar/emacs-head/HEAD-259dfd2_1/bin/emacs
```

Then you can make it and osascript to get in spotlight and applications:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to make alias file to POSIX file "/usr/local/Cellar/emacs-head/HEAD-259dfd2_1/Emacs.app" at POSIX file "/Applications"'
```

This is obsolete from now but it contains further information:
This is an update for October 2017. Now the easy to install emacs is using brew cask

```
brew cask install emacs
```

With this, it works well but I have an issue with gnutls and installing last org (9.1.6), but it worked well

for the traditional way and getting an emacs more integrated with your system or the nightly releases you can install with

```
brew install emacs --HEAD --with-cocoa --with-gnutls --with-librsvg --with-imagemagick@6 --with-mailutils
```

the --HEAD is not necessary, and now (23-01-2018) get Emacs 27, for the latest distributed without HEAD

then you should make this to use spotlight:

```
brew linkapps emacs
rm /Applications/Emacs.app
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to make alias file to POSIX file "/usr/local/opt/emacs/Emacs.app" at POSIX file "/Applications"'
```

and finally take a look at [emacs wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsForMacOS#toc14)

> Homebrew has Emacs 25.3 as of October 2017.
> Cask homebrew installation
>
> Homebrew now recommends to use the cask version with the following
> message: “Please try the Cask for a better-supported Cocoa version”
>
> To install the cask version:
>
> brew cask install emacs
>
> This installs a pre-built package from https://emacsformacosx.com/
> Standard homebrew installation
>
> If you prefer not to run the cask version, you can still use the old
> homebrew recipe.
>
> ```
> A Cocoa-specific Emacs.app can be built using the --with-cocoa switch.
> A version supporting X11 can be built using the --with-x switch. Note that this version will not have all of the features of the Cocoa
> ```
>
> version; use only if necessary.
>
> Other options include:
>
> ```
> --keep-ctags Don’t remove the ctags executable that emacs provides. Use of this flag is not recommended Instead, use brew
> ```
>
> install ctags after installation.
> --srgb This option will enable sRGB colors when using Cocoa.
>
> To install using the --with-cocoa switch, one simply uses:
>
> brew install --with-cocoa emacs
>
> to get some “pretty” colours add the --srgb switch:
>
> brew install --with-cocoa --srgb emacs
>
> and finally link it to your Applications folder:
>
> brew linkapps emacs
>
> This creates a symlink and not an alias. So Spotlight may not find it
> (tested on macOS Sierra 10.12.2). Spotlight indexes symlinks to files
> that are treated as system files, but it doesn’t show them in the GUI.
> It does show aliases though, so you could just command-option-drag
> /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/*/Emacs.app to /Applications/ from Finder. Or:
>
> $ osascript -e "tell application "Finder" to make alias file to
> (POSIX file "/usr/local/Cellar/emacs-plus/25.3/Emacs.app") at POSIX
> file "$HOME/Applications""
>
> After installation, using the emacs command in the terminal or shell
> will run the -nw version of Emacs. If you want to run the Cocoa
> version using this command, you simply add a line to your
> .bash_profile. Emacs-Plus version in tap
>
> To instead use the emacs-plus version, which is like regular homebrew
> emacs but with some configuration options enabled,
>
> brew tap d12frosted/emacs-plus brew install emacs-plus
>
> Mitsaharu version in tap
>
> To instead use the Yamamoto Mitsuharu version of Emacs 25.2 (with more
> mac-specific features):
>
> brew tap railwaycat/emacsmacport brew install emacs-mac
>
> and finally link it to your Applications folder:
>
> brew linkapps emacs-mac

Answer (score 20):

Actually, I don't know why we should do like other answers, why this post answers are complex? for installing `emacs` on Mac OSX just run below command in Mac terminal:

```
brew install --cask emacs
```

Then you have the latest version. just it.

Comment: The best way to install emacs is this.

Comment: Agreed, but I think if you already have a version of `emacs` then you should also `uninstall` it:
```
brew uninstall emacs
```

Answer (score 17):

**2022 update:**

```
brew install homebrew/cask/emacs
```

Is the best way to install emacs on mac now.

**Previous answer:**

You should be able to get yourself back to a sane state with `brew uninstall emacs` and `brew cleanup`.

Since brew and cask joined, now you can `brew install --cask emacs`. 
Assuming you want the GUI installed as well.

Comment: I have done the brew cask install emacs, which seems to have installed emacs 26.1, but when I invoke it "/usr/local/Cellar.../bin/emacs foo.txt" it does not come up with the GUI version, but the terminal version. How to invoke and get the GUI version (Mac OS), so I can still utilize the terminal? I had this working great on my old Macbook, which died horribly so I know it should be possible.

Comment: The GUI is at `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs` for me that is what the symlink points at.

`ls -lah /usr/local/bin/emacs`
`lrwxr-xr-x  1 adamhess  admin    44B Aug 21  2017 /usr/local/bin/emacs -> /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs`

Answer (score 1):

Using `brew`:

```
brew install --cask emacs
```

Credit goes to @[Mark McElroy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12549622/mark-mcelroy).

**Previous Answer:**

I would install Emacs from https://emacsformacos.com/

and create `/usr/local/bin/emacs` with:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs "$@"
```

Finally run:

```
chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/emacs
```

You can now run `emacs` from the command-line.

Comment: `brew install --cask emacs` installs the binary from https://emacsformacos.com/ for me

Answer (score 0):

To install emacs using the Mac terminal use command "brew install emacs" ONLY if home-brew is already installed. Otherwise install home-brew first using command /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)". Once home-brew is installed then you can use previous emacs command. After emacs is installed you can run brew services start emacs to successfully start emacs.

Answer (score 0):

I just uninstalled and reinstalled with

brew cask install emacs

Works ok. Unless you use org-mode.

Go into   /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/org

and take a look at org.el.gz

The very outdated Version 9.1.9.

What is very confusing is that he Org menu says the version is 9.3.7 and (org-version) reports the same.

Do a packages-list-packages and it correctly reports 9.1.9.

Guess how much of my time was wasted on this?